# How to calculate monthly data from weekly information in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my db,I saved data in weekly format like start_date of week and end_date of week, I want to show monthly data from that weekly data, but one condition is raised, if any week has in both month like(26-4-2013, 2-5-2013), so calculate this week data in month which has max no of week days.

Comment: I think you should consider going by dates, and not weeks. Like you can get monthly report from date 1 upto 30th or 31st, irrespective of where the week ended. Or what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i had saved data in weekly format, means startdate of week and end date of week, but now i want this data in months, means sum of all this weeks data which is in the relevant month, but if any week start  in one month and end with another month then , check one condition that if number of days of relevant week is more than 4 or 4 in any month then add this week data otherwise add in next month, for this scenario i want mysql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check two conditions in your query

1. If start date is >= "the last date of previous month minus 4 days "
2. If the end date is < "the 4th day of next month"

This should give the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;

CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have inserted data based on your above sample. Let me know if sample data is not correct.

```
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES (1,'2013-03-01','2013-03-07',10),(2,'2013-03-08','2013-03-14',50),(3,'2013-03-15','2013-03-21',60),(4,'2013-03-22','2013-03-28',30),(5,'2013-03-29','2013-04-04',80),(6,'2013-04-05','2013-04-11',90),(7,'2013-04-12','2013-04-18',70),(8,'2013-04-19','2013-04-25',20),(9,'2013-04-26','2013-05-02',40);
```

Check day of end_date column if it is greater than 3 then choose month from end_date column else choose month
from start_date column.

```
select if(day(end_date) > 3, month(end_date), month(start_date)) as monthname,sum(value)
from data
group by monthname
```

You can see id = 5 is considered in next month.